# Y-axis ticks in VS Code using Plotly

Tags: visual-studio, jupyter-notebook, plotly, xticks, yticks

As my 32 bit Jupyter Notebook isn't reading large CSV file. I started working with VS Code. I have a problem with the graph in VS code.

Output graph using VS Code:
[image]

The Y-axis ticks should be the same as the output graph in Jupyter Notebook. The below code is used in both VS Code and Jupyter.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.tools as plotly_tools
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
usedcolumns=['Time[s]','HIL_Input_Sources::DP_Vol.CurrentValue','HIL_Input_Sources::GE_Vol.CurrentValue','HIL_Input_Sources::CAM_RPM.RPM','HIL_Input_Sources::DP_Vol.RMS','HIL_Input_Sources::DP_Freq.Hz','HIL_Input_Sources::DP_Curr.CurrentValue','HCP4_CANFD02::Diagnose_01_XIX_HCP4_CANFD02::DW_Kilometerstand_XIX_Diagnose_01_XIX_HCP4_CANFD02[Unit_KiloMeter]']
chunksize = 1000
df = pd.read_csv('C:\Thesis\Log_Files\Input\Test_Log.csv',skipinitialspace=True, chunksize=chunksize, usecols=usedcolumns,sep=';',low_memory=True)
full_data=pd.concat(df,ignore_index=True)
full_data
pio.renderers.default = "vscode"
df1=full_data[['Time[s]','HIL_Input_Sources::DP_Vol.RMS']].copy()
print(df1)
fig=go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df1['Time[s]'], y = df1['HIL_Input_Sources::DP_Vol.RMS'],mode="lines"))
fig.update_layout(title='DP_Vol.RM',plot_bgcolor='rgb(230, 230,230)',showlegend=True)
fig.update_layout(xaxis = dict(tickmode = 'linear',dtick = 1,showgrid=True, gridwidth=1,griddash="dot", gridcolor='Black'))
fig.update_layout(yaxis = dict(tickmode = 'linear',tick0 = 0,dtick = 5,showgrid=True, gridwidth=1,griddash="dot", gridcolor='Black'))
fig.show()
```

But, I'm not able to produce the same graph in VS Code. For reference, I have attached the graph from Jupyter below.

Output graph using Jupyter:
[image]

Could anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance. I need the graph in VS Code as the graph in Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide [minimal reproducible code and sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Roxy. I have edit the code. But, I don't know why it's not showing as a code.

Comment: It is hard to help you without data. We need to reproduce the problem in our machine and help you. I suggest adding some data to help you. Or You can at least add some dummy data.

Comment: @Hamzah I can add some dummy data. But the problem is, the file has 161180 rows. I couldn't add it here. Thanks for editing the question.

Comment: Add data whose x between 33 and 77.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code and I'm able to get exact output graph in VS Code. Thanks for your support.

```
fig.update_layout(autotypenumbers='convert types')
```